# Hierarchical taxonomy fileds' values as node path in Drupal 7

Tags: tokens, path-aliases, taxonomy-terms

I have a vocabulary with 2 levels of terms. As my term names are usually rather long (e.g. "Institute of Computer Science and Information Technology") I added a field "short_name" to the vocabulary (e.g. "ICSIT"). Now I am working on creating Pathauto term aliases for node paths. I need it like this:

[short_name of term level 1]/[short_name of term level 2]/[node_title]

The problem is that can't find the right token to achieve this behaviour. Is it possible? Any ideas?

Comment: The easiest way to achieve this is to use the sort name as the term, and the full name as a term alias.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Triskelion! Unfortunately using the short name as a term name is not an option for us (the term pages are used as content pages with lots of fields etc). Could you please explain what you mean by "term alias"?

Comment: Sorry. Synonyms. Used to be in core up to Drupal 6. In Druppal 7 requires the [Synonyms](http://drupal.org/project/synonyms) module.